# C# - Download img and converting bytes to bitmap only works with Fiddler open

Tags: c#, .net, image

I am connecting to a site over SSL using HttpWebRequest, downloading an image, then converting the bytes to a bitmap which I can load in a picture box.

Everything works fine if Fiddler is open but if it's closed, I get the error **Parameter is not valid.** when passing the MemoryStream to the Bitmap constructor.

Any ideas what's going on? I assume it's Fiddler's cert doing something but why the hell would it WORK with Fiddler running? I tried the app from another location (without Fiddler installed) and got the same error as above.

```
public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] bytes)
{
   MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
   byte[] data = bytes;
   mStream.Write(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(data.Length));
   Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);   //**Problem line**
   mStream.Dispose();
   return bm;
}
public static byte[] GetImageBytes()
{
   // CODE FOR HttpWebRequest HERE

   byte[] response;
   using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
   response = Parser.ResponseAsBytes(resp);
   return response;
}

public static byte[] ResponseAsBytes(HttpWebResponse response)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream stream;
                if (response == null || (stream = response.GetResponseStream()) == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) return null;
                byte[] bytes;
                using (stream)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[5000];
                    while ((stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0) { }
                    return bytes;
                }
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you are behind a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
      System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(YourURLString);
      System.Net.WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
      System.IO.Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
      Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(respStream);
      respStream.Dispose();
      picturebox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: i actually did this right after i posted the question and found that it worked. but you got it right. thanks!!